# Is there a way to use stacked bar chart with Apexcharts (or similar) and have the data be separated?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, stacked-chart, apexcharts

I would like to have my data as follows:

*first_stacked_bar*: (Label) **Math** | (Data, all Math courses I have taken) **Math_course_1, Math_course_2 ....**

*second_stacked_bar*: (Label) **Physics** | (Data) **Physics_course_1, Physics_course_2 ....**

*third_stacked_bar*: (Label) **Economy** | (Data) **Economy_course_1, Economy_course_2 ....**

That is, I would like to have multiple stacked bars in one graph without any connection between them (the first Math course does not have a relationship to the first Physics or Economy course). Looking at the examples in several chart packages this is not the case (compare with e.g. https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/bar-charts/stacked/# where each first data entry is shared "Marine Sprite").

At the moment I am splitting up every row into its own chart which is ~working but not very well or with a pretty outcome.

If anyone has a chart package to recommend or ideas to share I would be very happy. I'm using Vue.js for my project so if it also works with Vue that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Stacked graph without relations]

So I finally made it work with Apexcharts.

CODE:

*EducationCharts*

```
<div>
<div v-for="(area, i) in getAreas" :key="i">
  <EducationCoursesChart :school="school" :area="area" />
</div>
```

*EducationChart*

```
<div id="barchart">
    <div class="barChartAreaWrapper">
      <p class="barChartArea">{{area}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="barChartDataWrapper">
      <apexchart
        class="barChartData"
        type="bar"
        height="30"
        :options="chartOptions"
        :series="getCourses"
      ></apexchart>
    </div>
  </div>
```

*method GetCourses:*

```
getCourses() {
      var courses = [];
      this.school.courses.forEach(course => {
        var dataArray = [];
        if (course.area === this.area) {
          dataArray.push(course.credits);
          courses.push({ name: course.name, data: dataArray });
        }
      });
      return courses;
    }
```

There might be better ways of fixing this issue, but as you can see from the code above, I decided on making a new chart for each area. To make them more in sync I modified the chartOptions quite a lot. You can see the changes below.

*chartOptions:*

```
chartOptions: {
    colors: [
      this.school.color,
      this.adjustColor(this.school.color, 40),
      this.adjustColor(this.school.color, 80),
      this.adjustColor(this.school.color, 120),
      this.adjustColor(this.school.color, 200),
      this.adjustColor(this.school.color, 280)
    ],
    chart: {
      type: "bar",
      height: "auto",
      stacked: true,
      toolbar: {
        tools: {
          download: false
        }
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: true,
        barHeight: "70%"
      }
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 1,
      colors: ["black"]
    },
    grid: {
      padding: {
        top: -35,
        bottom: -20
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 41,
      categories: [""],
      labels: {
        show: false
      },
      axisBorder: {
        show: false
      },
      axisTicks: {
        show: false
      },
      position: "none"
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      theme: "light",
      x: {
        show: false
      }
    }
  }
```